# When I run the site in a subdomain, I need to declare that subdomain in the .env file

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Installation is ok. But looks like you are running the site under a subdomain. When you run the site in a subdomain, you need to declare that subdomain in the .env file.

```
IGNORE_SUBDOMAINS="www,menu"
```

I am using Larvel and my .env looks like this:

```
APP_LOG_LEVEL=debug
APP_URL=https://menu.bethello.com/
APP_LOCALE=en
IGNORE_SUBDOMAINS=menu.bethello.com
TIME_ZONE="America/New_York"
CASHIER_CURRENCY=USD
```

Comment: Didn't `IGNORE_SUBDOMAINS="www,menu"` fix your problem?